# Redmine Java Api - org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1

Tags: java, redmine, redmine-api

When I try run this code (The Issue example is taken from this web http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Rest_api_with_java ) :

```
    RedmineManager redmineManager = new RedmineManager("http://something.cz", "somekey"); //I changed these two parameters for security reasons when paste here
    System.out.println(redmineManager.getProjects().size()); //this works fine
    Issue issueToCreate = new Issue();
    issueToCreate.setSubject("This is the summary line 123");
    Issue newIssue = redmineManager.createIssue("test-project", issueToCreate); //this line throws exception
```

It ends with this exception

```
Exception in thread "main" com.taskadapter.redmineapi.RedmineFormatException: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
    at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:456)
    at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.addObject(Transport.java:186)
    at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.RedmineManager.createIssue(RedmineManager.java:135)
    at javaapplication146.JavaApplication146.main(JavaApplication146.java:27)
Caused by: org.json.JSONException: A JSONObject text must begin with '{' at character 1
    at org.json.JSONTokener.syntaxError(JSONTokener.java:410)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:179)
    at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:402)
    at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.RedmineJSONParser.getResponseSingleObject(RedmineJSONParser.java:609)
    at com.taskadapter.redmineapi.internal.Transport.parseResponse(Transport.java:454)
    ... 3 more
Java Result: 1
```

The same behaviour is for any other "get some objects" (which works) and for "create some objects" (which does not).

I am using maven ( http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.taskadapter/redmine-java-api ) with its dependency for version 1.23, however I tried 1.12.0 and same exception was thrown.

We are using latest redmine 2.5.1.stable, however based on stacktrace, the communication between redmine web and this redmine api does not happen as the exception is thrown in "parseRespone" part of application.