# SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED when connecting trino to superset

Tags: google-cloud-dataproc, apache-superset, trino

Cannot connect trino ( dataproc ) to apache superset.
[image: error SSL]

Dataproc details:

`gcloud dataproc clusters create cluster-name 
--region region 
--optional-components=TRINO 
--image-version 2.1-debian11 
--enable-component-gateway 
--scopes=cloud-platform 
--enable-kerberos

On the Trino cluster (on the master node):

I copied the self-signed Trino certificate to the /usr/local/share/ca-certificates/ directory and ran the sudo update-ca-certificates command to update the certificate store.
`

Comment: `/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/` might not be the right place. You might need to add it to Java https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25951602/adding-an-ssl-certificate-to-jre-in-order-to-access-https-sites